# How do you output the row value of an HTML table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console.log the value of a row in a table. I am able to console.log the row index on click, but outputting the actual row value is proving a bit more challenging. I'm pretty new at JavaScript, so I suspect (and hope) it's something simple and a lightbulb opportunity as well.

HTML

```
<form id="location-form">
     <textarea name="excel_data" id="data-paste" class="form-control 
      form-control-md" style="height:150px;"></textarea><br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
      style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;" 
      onclick="javascript:generateTable(); return false;">Submit
     </button>
</form>

<h2 style="text-align: center;">Table will appear below: </h2>
     <div class="location-table" style="margin:25px auto;">
     <table id="excel_table" class="table loc-table table-sm table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%;"></table>         
     </div>
```

JavaScript

```
// Get data inserted into the textarea and put in table below it //

   function generateTable() {
      var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
      console.log(data);
      var rows = data.split("\n");

      var table = $('<table id="new_table" />');

      for (var y in rows) {
         var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
         var row = $('<tr />');
         for (var x in cells) {
             row.append('<td>' + cells[x] + '</td>');
             console.log(cells[x]);
             }

// only append rows with text - do not append blank rows
   if (cells[x].length > 0) {
      table.append(row);
      }                
   }

// Insert into DOM
$('#excel_table').html(table);

// Action when click on a row in the table
var locTable = document.getElementById('new_table'), rIndex;

    for(var i =  0; i < locTable.rows.length; i++)
       {
          locTable.rows[i].onclick = function()
          {
          rIndex = this.rowIndex;
          console.log("the value of the rIndex variable is " + rIndex);
          var loc_string = this.rows[rIndex].innerHTML;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(loc_string));
          }   
       }
    }
```

It's something in the last block of code in the click event. I probably included too much code, but for context, I included the code that creates the table from values in a textarea.

It's giving me "110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLTableRowElement.locTable.rows..onclick"

Comment: Not sure the duplicate @certainperformance linked to will reveal what you're after.  For something very simple, try utilizing this: `let rows = document.querySelector('tbody')
let arr = [...rows.children].map(tr=>[...tr.children].map(td=>td.textContent))
console.table(arr);`  This makes use of the `console.table()`, which is good for debugging.

Comment: This answer was more focused on my issue. Now I am able to parse the value from the array based on the index (which I was already successfully outputting on row click). Thanks a million for steering me in that direction @vol7ron!